# Installing a service which runs all the time without user action, even after reboot

Tags: android, service

I need to develop an app which runs a background task. Once the app is installed it should run all the time. There is no UI to start the task, it should autmomatically run after the app is installed.
Also it should still run after a reboot.

All examples I have found describe how to start a service from within a running app. But in my case I have no UI, so the user cannot start the app.

Is this not possible for safety reasons?

Comment: Security is one thing, battery saving is another. Background services are also heavily restricted since android O and will be automatically killed few minutes after user haven't interacted with your app.

Comment: Is that a **virus** you are trying to make?! What is the sense of making a **hidden** app (without a UI)?

Comment: Of course not... I have an Android Headunit which changes volume when pressing car keys. I tried many volume lock apps but none of them worked. So I wrote an app which sets the volume to 100% every 100ms. This seems to work. But I do not want to start the app every time I start the car. So the only solution is probably to use an Autostart utility once Android has booted?

Comment: It can be an option.

Answer (score 0):

> Once the app is installed it should run all the time

That has never been possible, in any version of Android. Processes do not run forever. The closest that you have ever been able to come is a foreground service, but that involves a UI (`Notification`).

> There is no UI to start the task, it should autmomatically run after the app is installed.

That has not been possible since Android 3.1, which was released about seven years ago.

> Is this not possible for safety reasons?

If "this" is the "it should autmomatically run after the app is installed" part, then yes.